# How to sum up values of occuring chars from a string, make them pairs and sort them in ascending order?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, std-pair

My task is to write a function that gets a vector of strings as an argument, and returns a vector of `pair<char,int>` containing pairs representing characters and their frequency (how much times the letter has appeared) summed up from all strings passed in vector as an argument of the function. It should also be sorted in ascending order.

The code below is my approach on how to do it. So far I'm only able to count how many times the character occured in every string, but I'm not able to sum all of the occuring letters to be the one pair.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isEqual(const pair<char, int> &element) {
    return element.first;
}

vector<pair<char, int>> all_occurrences(vector<string> vec) {

    vector<pair<char, int>> sorted_vec;
    vector<pair<char, int>> final_vec;

    char c;
    int count_chars = 0;
    string element;
    vector<char> check_chars = {' '};
    bool char_found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {

        element = vec[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < element.length(); j++) {

            c = element.at(j);

            for (int k = 0; k < check_chars.size(); ++k) {
                if (c == check_chars[k]) {
                    char_found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!char_found) {
                check_chars.push_back(c);
                count_chars = count(element.begin(), element.end(), c);
                sorted_vec.push_back(make_pair(c, count_chars));
            }

            char_found = false;

        }
        check_chars = {' '};
    }

    vector<pair<char, int>>::iterator it;

    for (int i = 0; i < sorted_vec.size(); ++i) {

        it = find_if(sorted_vec.begin(), sorted_vec.end(), isEqual);
        cout << it << endl;

    }


    return sorted_vec;
}

void print_vector(vector<pair<char, int>> pair_vector) {

    cout << "---" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_vector.size(); i++) {
        cout << pair_vector[i].first << ',' << pair_vector[i].second << endl;
    }

    cout << "---" << endl;

}


int main() {

    vector<string> string_vector = {"ala", "ma", "kota"};
    print_vector(all_occurrences(string_vector));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the solution (the code for `all_occurences`) is around 5 or 6 lines if you're willing to use `std::unordered_map` and a couple of STL algorithm functions.

Comment: *i've probably lost some hair due to that because its been literally two weeks.* -- And you got an answer within 10 minutes.  Don't get spoiled by this, since we expect you to learn from the answer given, and not simply copy it and hand it in to your teacher.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for clarifying that, i do know that here i can ask for answers for tasks that i dont yet understand - and i dont expect anyone to let me copy & paste the code without me understanding it. Its much more satisfying when you get the answer by yourself, but sometimes undoable when you are just a begginer. Either way, i will analyse it more and read about it for a while so i get some more knowledge about this solution that seems very clean to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can calculate all the frequency counts with a `std::map`:

```
std::map<char,int> m;
for(auto c : vec | std::views::join)  // for every char in all strings
    m[c]++;
```

Then you can copy this `map` into a `vector` as needed:

```
vector<pair<char, int>> res;
std::ranges::copy(m, std::back_inserter(res));
```

And finally you can sort the vector in ascending order of the frequency counts:

```
std::ranges::sort(res, std::less{}, &std::pair<char, int>::second);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E1Gsa1).

---

Pre C++20, you can write the above code like this:

Construct a frequency count:

```
std::map<char,int> m;
for (auto const &s : vec)  // for every string
    for(auto c : s)        // for every character
        m[c]++;            // add to the frequency count
```

Copy into a vector:

```
vector<pair<char, int>> res;
std::copy(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(res));
```

And sort it:

```
std::sort(res.begin(), res.end(), [](auto a, auto b) {
    return a.second < b.second;
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YssK1j).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. That is exactly what i needed. And it seems like using map is much shorter and time efficient than my idea for that. As i said, im new to C++ and i've been only programming in java till now, so i kinda get lost in the syntax sometimes and cant always understand what some functions are for. Nontheless, this is a great answer and it explains a lot about map functionality. Thank you again.

Comment: @Insekure No problem, glad to help :) As Paul said in a comment above, make sure to take the effort to understand the solution and why it works. It'll be really helpful in the long run.

Comment: Im aware, thats why im here asking for help and better solutions, and not just asking some of my friends to make it for me. I want to understand it, and i will - i just need to read about it for a while and get some more in-depth knowledge. Thank you again.

Comment: One more question, to the actual sorting mechanism. How does it work exactly? Is [](auto a, auto b)  lambda? Can i use the (pair a, pair b) type to do it, or does it only work with auto?

Comment: @Insekure The `auto` is just a shortcut, but a very helpful one.  You could also have done this the long way by using `(const std::pair<char,int>& a, const std::pair<char,int>& b)`, but you see how much longer that is.

Comment: @Insekure BTW, In Java, the solution would use the same approach.  A "List" to keep track of the character and count, similar to `std::map`, and copy the results to an array to be sorted.